# why is ypbind failing to start?

Tags: linux, services, centos-7

trying to setup NIS server.
client : **labipa.example.com**
server : **server1.example.com**

with the steps mentioned [here for server](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=nis&f=1) and [here for client](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=nis&f=2)

but `ypbind` is not starting on client

```
systemctl start ypbind
Job for ypbind.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ypbind.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`journalctl -xe` gives error :

```
Oct 17 08:33:05 labipa.example.com pulseaudio[3815]: [alsa-sink] alsa-util.c: Unable to set sw params: Permission denied
Oct 17 08:33:05 labipa.example.com pulseaudio[3815]: [alsa-sink] alsa-sink.c: Failed to set software parameters: Permission den
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command as root, or using sudo?

Comment: yes, i am getting this error as root